# magento 2 round the price by considering decimal points

Tags: magento-2.0

i want to round my price like AED67.58 to AED67.6 then to AED68. that means i want to remove the decimals by considering valuable decimals.

Answer (score -3):

Edit file

`/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/PriceCurrencyInterface.php`

Set
`const DEFAULT_PRECISION = 0;`

Then flush cache.

Comment: This is not a solution, you should never ever manually edit any files in the `vendor` directory. These are third party libraries and should not be touched.

Comment: Thanks Danny, I did not know that. But the price-utils.js solution in other posts did not work in my situation. It took me half an hour to track the code. Just hope it helps someone else.